# setTimeout выполнение до завершения

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую выполняется функция через `setTimeout(f, 250);`
Но если нажать быстро на кнопку много раз, запуститься одновременно много функций
Вопрос: можно ли сделать так, что бы при многкратном нажатии функция не выполнялась до тех пор, пока  не закончит выполнение предыдущая функция

Answer (score 5):

```
var timer = null;
function clickHandler() {
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      f();
      timer = null;
    }, 250);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, очередь из функций проще всего сделать цепочкой обещаний:

```js
let lastDeferr,
count=0
$('button').click(()=>{
  //создаём новое обещание
  let promise=new $.Deferred(),
  //устанавливаем функцию-обработчик
  fn=()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('You click button '+(++count)+' times')
      promise.resolve()
    },1000)
    return promise
  }
  //создаём новую цепочку или продолжаем уже имеющуюся
  lastDeferr?lastDeferr.then(fn):fn()
  //запоминаем последнее звено цепочки обещаний
  lastDeferr=promise
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>This is button</button>
```

Comment: ему не нужна очередь функций, ему нужно, что бы функция выполнялась, не чаще чем в N миллисекунд

Comment: @ThisMan а я изначально подумал иначе. Вопрос сформулирован так, что нельзя сказать это наверняка.

Comment: _что бы при многкратном нажатии функция не выполнялась до тех пор, пока не закончит выполнение предыдущая функция_ хоть и с ошибками, но вроде как однозначно

Comment: @ThisMan нет, я это до сих пор понимаю как: я запускаю много функций при нажатии и хочу, чтобы каждая запущенная функция выполнялась только после того, как выполнилась предыдущая.